# How can I make this responsive website stretch across the entire screen?

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design, responsiveness

I have a website that is giving me a ton of trouble with the site not fitting the width of the screen. I tried changing the viewport meta tag but nothing seems to work properly. I have included a screenshot at the below link. You can see a huge margin on the right hand side on iPhone. Please any help is appreciated as I am stumped!

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkiKd.jpg)

Comment: Can you give some css and html codes? It's too hard to help this manner

Comment: Without any code or example it is very hard to know what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any code for us to look at, but you should have a "wrapper" element that contains all the other content. That wrapper, if it were a div would stretch to 100% of the viewport width. Child elements in the wrapper would need to be responsive as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the URL from your screen shot. In the "Group Fitness" section you have an embedded image with width: 649px

```
<img style="width: 649px;" src="<massive data removed...>" data-filename="IMG_3105.JPG">
```

You should remove the style from that img tag, or set it to a %.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the prior answer, I looked into your live site source code. Following repeated `&nbsp;` s creating the error.

```
<h2>
    <span style="font-weight: normal;">
        <span>INSANITY LIVE<br>
            <font color="#efefef" style="background-color: inherit;">Monday&nbsp;6:00pm</font>
        </span>
        <font color="#efefef" style="background-color: inherit;">   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
      Wednesday 6:00am
        </font>
    </span>
</h2>
```

If those extra characters are dynamic, quick fix with @media would be

```
font[style^=background] { display: inline-block;}
```